# Filter IDs of the last "boot event" from Event Log in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, event-log, boot

I need to filter IDs of the last "boot event" from Event Log

I get it by running **psloglist -accepteula -n 1  -s  -o "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General" -i  12 -t ;** that I redirect to a file and need to filter only the first chunk of numbers followed by ; on second line as shown in example bellow

> System log on \FDU000084151005:
>   **107604**;System;Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General;INFORMATION;FDU000084151005

could you please, please, help me write that in powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of how you can get it with `Get-WinEvent`:

```
get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{ProviderName = "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General" ; Id = 12} |
select -expand RecordId
```

Comment: Thank you, I just need to filter the last one but combining it with help from Shay Levy bellow I was able to get it, thanks to both of you :-)

Comment: yay `get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{ProviderName = "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General" ; Id = 12} | select -expand RecordId | select-object -first 1`

Answer (score 0):

You probably can get the values with the `Get-WinEvent` cmdlet, check the help examples. I don't have that log file on my system so I can't give you a working example.

Here's a way to extract the values from the exported file using the match operator and the $matches collection:

```
Get-Content log.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match '^(\d+);'} | Foreach-Object { $matches[1] }
```